# Generating different combinations of string in python

Tags: python, string, algorithm

I am working on a project and stuck at the point I am discussing below.
I have sets of permissions. P0, P1 etc. Permissions can be individual like P0, P1, P2 etc or in groups P1P2, P3P4P5, P1P7P11P34......the permissions are treated as strings and we have them in in sorted order(based on length). Here is one possible sequence of input strings:
    P1
    P2
    P4
    P23
    P0P1
    P3P5
    P8P13P45P67
    ..........
    .......

Now my work is to see if each longer string can be formed by some combination of the smaller strings. What I am doing is I am inserting the strings into a trie and checking whether the larger strings can be made using the previous string. If yes, I am doing nothing; otherwise, I put the latest seen string into the trie.

The problem I have is that, as the length of the strings increase, I have to do permutations/combinations of the strings and check whether they are present or not. Now the classic string permutations will not work, because first I have to have all the permutations together (not one by one) to check if they are in the trie.  The permutation is order specific so P0P1 is feasible and not P1P0.  Also, there are far too many permutations.

I am giving an example of the different combinations to make it more clear. Suppose I have a new permission string like P0P1P2. The different combinations I have to check before declaring that my previous entries in the trie is not suitable to build the string.

Note that the permutation must not include any permissions *not* in the target (new input) string.

`P0 P1 P2 
 P0P1 P2
 P0P1 P1P2
 P0P1 P0P2
 P0P2 P1
 P0P2 P0P1
 P0 P1P2`

I am stuck at this point and want to know if there is some algorithm which generates such combinations for a very large strings, or I have to drop this idea and go in a different route.

Comment: As you already know, this is not a trivial problem.  Are you allowed to have overlap?  For instance, can you make P0P1P2 from only P0P1 and P1P2?  Must the permissions be contiguous -- can you make P0P1P2 from P0P2 and P1?  These specification details greatly affect the application.

Comment: Yes I am allowed to make P0P1P2 from P0P1 and P1P2 and also from P0P2 and P1...

Comment: What abou the following: are you allowed to make P0P1P2 from `P0P3`, `P1P3` and `P2P3`?

Comment: no...basically any permission that is not in the initial string cannot be in the sub-string as well...

Comment: And what are "the initial string" and "the sub-string"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misread your problem statement earlier: I thought you had to obtain the permissions in a given order, such that P0P1 would later not be sufficient to cover a line of P1P0.  Sorry about the delay.

I suggest an alternative to bit vectors: sets.  They're slower, but automatically expandable, and perhaps easier to use.  The process for each input line is:

- Extract the permission numbers into a set.
- Clear out the master set.
- For each prior string,
- If the prior is a subset of the current string (no extra permissions),
- add it to the master set.
- Check the master set; if it is a superset of the input line,
- Report that the new string is covered by the priors;
- else add the new string to the priors list.

I'm also assuming that you don't need to know *which* prior input lines are needed to cover the current one.

Code:

```
prior = []    # list of prior input sets (only those that weren't redundant)

with open("permission.txt") as in_file:
  for in_line in in_file:
    master = set([])
    perm_line = set([int(s) for s in in_line.split('P') if len(s)>0])

    # Check each of the shorter (prior) permission strings
    for short in prior:
      # If the prior string has no superfluous permissions, add it to the master set.
      extra = short - perm_line
      if len(extra) == 0:
        master = master.union(short)

    # Did the combination of prior strings cover all of the input line permissions?
    print in_line,
    if len(perm_line - master) == 0:
      print "\tPermissions included in prior strings"
    else:
      print "\tFound New permission combinations; adding to reference list"
      prior.append(perm_line)
```

Output: (input file echoed to make that part obvious; I added a few lines)

```
P1
    Found New permission combinations; adding to reference list
P2
    Found New permission combinations; adding to reference list
P4
    Found New permission combinations; adding to reference list
P23
    Found New permission combinations; adding to reference list
P0P1
    Found New permission combinations; adding to reference list
P3P5
    Found New permission combinations; adding to reference list
P8P13P45P67
    Found New permission combinations; adding to reference list
P0P2
    Found New permission combinations; adding to reference list
P0P1P3P5
    Permissions included in prior strings
P0P1P2
    Permissions included in prior strings
P0P1P2P3
    Found New permission combinations; adding to reference list
```

---

UPDATE: Here's how to track the permission sets used to make the new string.  Focus on the new objects **cover** and **cover_team**.  Note that this does not find the *minimal* coverage, although you'll get close to that if you add new elements to **prior** at the front, rather than the end.  This makes the routine search from longest to shortest.

I've taken the "cheap" way out for reporting, just printing the permission sets.  I'll let you worry about the formatting.

```
prior = [] # list of prior input sets (only those that weren't redundant)

with open("permission.txt") as in_file:
  for in_line in in_file:
    master = set([])
    cover = set([])
    cover_team = []
    perm_line = set([int(s) for s in in_line.split('P') if len(s)>0])

    # Check each of the shorter (prior) permission strings
    for short in prior:
      # If the prior string has no superfluous permissions, add it to the master set.
      extra = short - perm_line
      if len(extra) == 0:
        master = master.union(short)
        # Does this string add anything new to the coverage?
        ### print "compare", short, cover
        if len(short - cover) > 0:
          cover = cover.union(short)
          cover_team.append(short)
          ### print "Add to cover_team:", short

    # Did the combination of prior strings cover all of the input line permissions?
    print in_line,
    if len(perm_line - master) == 0:
      print "\tPermissions included in prior strings", cover_team
    else:
      print "\tFound New permission combinations; adding to reference list"
      prior.append(perm_line)
```

Output:

```
P1
    Found New permission combinations; adding to reference list
P2
    Found New permission combinations; adding to reference list
P4
    Found New permission combinations; adding to reference list
P23
    Found New permission combinations; adding to reference list
P0P1
    Found New permission combinations; adding to reference list
P3P5
    Found New permission combinations; adding to reference list
P8P13P45P67
    Found New permission combinations; adding to reference list
P0P2
    Found New permission combinations; adding to reference list
P0P1P3P5
    Permissions included in prior strings [set([1]), set([0, 1]), set([3, 5])]
P0P1P2
    Permissions included in prior strings [set([1]), set([2]), set([0, 1])]
P0P1P2P3
    Found New permission combinations; adding to reference list
P0P1P2P3P4P5
    Permissions included in prior strings [set([1]), set([2]), set([4]), set([0, 1]), set([3, 5])]
```

Comment: We have to add the permission P0P2 and P0P8P23 because when we entered P0 it was grouped with P1 and not individual like P1. And as my new string doesn't contain P1 I cannot include P0. Same with the other example...

Comment: It sounds like your description needs clarification.  We have to make the input string from some combination of prior inputs, *but with no extra permissions in that combination*?  Is this correct?

Comment: so in_file will be my shorted list of permissions

Comment: Right; I just filled it with the strings you posted, adding a few more test cases of my own.  It's a simple text file.

Comment: Hi Prune I know it's late to ask but I have another query. like what if I wanted to know which prior strings are needed to cover the current one.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to create a structure of all possible permission strings that can be created, since this grows exponentially with the number of strings.

Here's an alternative: you can represent each permission string as a bit vector (using Python's [BitVector package](https://engineering.purdue.edu/kak/dist/BitVector-3.4.4.html), where bit i of the vector is set whenever the corresponding permission P[i] is included in your string...this works since the order of the permissions doesn't matter.

Suppose you have a list of your permission bit vectors called bv which is already sorted on length. Then you can create your reduced list as follows (I'm assuming only 68 permissions, 0 through 67, given your example):

`for v in bv:
   coll = BitVector(intval=0, size=68)  # Null vector
   for x in reduced:                    # Look at all accepted strings
     if (x & v == x):                   # If all permissions in x are needed
       coll = coll | x                  # Record this as a possible substring
   if (coll != v):                      # If some permission is missing
     reduced.append(v)                  # String can't be represented`

As an example, if reduced contains P0, P1, P1P2, and P2P3, and the next value is v=P0P1P2, then coll = P0 | P1 | P1P2 = P0P1P2. Since this is the string we're testing, we don't push it on the reduced list.

If the subsequent value is v=P0P1P3, then coll = P0 | P1, which is not equal to v, so this value is added. This occurs because you can't get P3 without also taking P2.

Comment: bv is a list of bit vectors that represent the permissions in your list, sorted on length.

Comment: I have tested the one u suggested with small samples and it's working. Now have to test with original data....